# Replace lambda with a function

Tags: c#, lambda, functional-programming

If I write this code, it works:

```
closestInPrice = list.OrderBy
                    (item => Math.Abs(2 * item.mid - price)).ToList();
```

If instead I try to replace the `lambda` with a `function`:

```
static double ComputeSpread(double mid, double price)
{
            return (2 * mid) - price;
}

Func<double, double, double> computeSpread = ComputeSpread;

closestInPrice = list.OrderBy(computeSpread).ToList();
```

it says the "type can't be inferred try explicitly":

Comment: Yes -- because `OrderBy` needs a function that takes *one* parameter, not two. Your lambda takes `item` as a parameter, but `price` is taken from the context (as a closure). To do the same with a function, you would need to put `price` in a field (or use partial application: `Func<double, double> computeSpread = (item) => ComputeSpread(item, price)`, though of course under the covers this is another lambda!)

Answer (score 2):

Part of your original lamba expression was accessing an object property, so you either need to explicitly pass that value when calling the function, or change the parameters of `ComputeSpread` to accept an `item`:

```
static double ComputeSpread(TClass item, double price)
{
    return (2 * item.mid) - price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `computeSpread`, but you do need to modify `ComputeSpread` to accept a single argument:

```
static double ComputeSpread(X item) //change X to whatever type is stored in your list
{
    return (2 * item.mid) - item.price;
}


closestInPrice = list.OrderBy(ComputeSpread).ToList();
```

You can also form your ComputeSpread like:

```
static double ComputeSpread(X item)  => (2 * item.mid) - item.price;
```

... would you do it? It depends how reusable you want ComputeSpread to be...

ps; If you put it in another class you might have to qualify it with a type and/or namespace name

```
closestInPrice = list.OrderBy(Helpers.ComputeSpread).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change the `ComputeSpread` helper method. Just define `computeSpread` as a new function:

```
Func<Item, double> computeSpread = item => ComputeSpread(item.mid, price);
var closestInPrice = list.OrderBy(computeSpread).ToList();
```

This assumes that `price` is a local variable that `computeSpread` can close over.